Question about low voltage from mains for tube amplifier 811h
Edit: So I guess what i really want to know is more technical question regarding 572b tubes. What plate voltage is minimum to safely drive 572b tubes? what is lowest filament voltage to optimally drive 572b tubes? I know I should have never mentioned the amplifier, I realize they are plagued with problems, and looking back I want to know more about 572b tubes parameters. I won't edit initial post for clarity.
And it seems you are all missing extra information that there is an built in option to rewire safely for line voltage of 110 volts, since I normally see 110-115 mains voltage, I am thinking of rewiring to this and see what the plate voltage will then rise to, which brings me back to question above regarding 572b tubes
My mains voltage usually measures between 110-115. I think most I seen it was 118 volts.
I notice my plate voltage for Ameritron 811h using 4 572bs (drop in replacements for 811a) is slightly higher than 1.5 Kv  on idle/stand by according to the meter. (not sure how accurate it can be...)
under load it goes even lower, as expected.
The amplifier, according to the manual is wired default for 120v, which I have checked inside and it is according to manual diagram.
My questions: I'm I putting components under stress for having lower voltage then wired for? (The transformer? the tubes? )
If I rewire (which is to say simply jumping over a solder joint to other point on board) for the optional 110v setting, will I be causing damage, since I do see voltage around 115 and sometimes slightly higher.
Better to leave it as is assuming nothing is potentially being damaged or stressed? ( I don't care about more power out, I run the tubes light, with only 50 watt drive)
or rewire for 110 V, but since I do see between 110-118 volts, will those extra volts do damage?

Thing works now, and is not even 10% below nominal voltage (which is perfectly normal). So, don't touch a running system – by rewiring it, you will certainly not make it less susceptible to failure!

Manual says: "Regulation: 15%", so an abberation of < 10% is fully within what the device specifies. (as an EE, I'd have something to say about regulation so bad, but I guess the operator is simply part of the control loop and will just crank up the gain if necessary)

thanks, so technically, if i rewire as stated in manual, for 110 volts , it is also ok... I will rewire for 110 volts and see what my plate voltage is then, btw, the 572bs are Penta Lab tubes, from what I read, they are considered decent tubes made today, they are based in California.

Why would you first ask for advice, then get the clear advice that you have no problem that would require solution, and that you should not rewire, then decide to do it anyways? I mean, it's definitely in the realm of your personal freedom, it just brings the question of whether you actually wanted advice or hoped for confirmation.

As the edit says, turns out I want more advice for those who know about operating conditions for 572b tubes.  I will rewire for 110 volts, read plate voltage then, no one on here has answered for details on 572b tubes, but search on other places says 572bs can easily handle 2000 plate voltage,  Seems no one is actually reading my post.

I'm reading your post. And you were asking about putting your tubes under stress. Operating them closer to maximum plate voltage than necessary puts them under stress. You're achieving the opposite of what you wanted.


My questions: I'm I putting components under stress for having lower voltage then wired for? (The transformer? the tubes? )

No. Just don't overdrive the input trying to get more output than is possible. When the grid current meter says stop, stop.

If I rewire (which is to say simply jumping over a solder joint to other point on board) for the optional 110v setting, will I be causing damage, since I do see voltage around 115 and sometimes slightly higher.

The tubes can take it (they're rated for over 2500V plate voltage). Other parts of the amplifier (like filter capacitors) may not. The red zone on the front panel meter is there for a reason: don't go there. A deviation of less than 10% is fairly unlikely to be a problem, but why do it unless you're trying to squeeze every last watt out?

Better to leave it as is assuming nothing is potentially being damaged or stressed?

Yes. There's no problem and nothing for you to improve by making a change.

So I guess what i really want to know is more technical question regarding 572b tubes. What plate voltage is minimum to safely drive 572b tubes?

Ignoring the rest of the amplifier, there's really no such thing. You can drop the plate voltage far, far lower than the 811 does and the tube will work just fine (at correspondingly lower power, of course). 400V is no problem.

what is lowest filament voltage to optimally drive 572b tubes?

The datasheet says 6.3V±0.3, so 6 volts is your working minimum.
